# If I want to work in UK, do I need a Visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, visa, brexit

Now that Brexit happened, if someone from the EU wants to work in UK, do they need a Visa, Permit, or anything similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not before the [transition period](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-50838994) ends (31 December 2020):

> During this period, the UK will remain in both the EU customs union
>   and single market.
>
> That means, until the transition ends, most things will stay the same.
>   This includes:
>
> - Travelling to and from the EU (including the rules around driving
>     licences and pet passports)
> - Freedom of movement (the right to live and
>     work in the EU and vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you want to stay in the U.K. beyond Jan 2021, you will have to apply for “pre-settled” status which allows you to remain with short interruptions, and you can change this to “settled status” after being in the U.K. for five years, which allows you to leave and return within five years.

I wouldn’t be surprised if the U.K. enforced freedom-of-movement rules more strictly, like you have to actually work if you move to the U.K. to work, similar to other EU countries.

Comment: "have to actually work if you move to the U.K. to work": what are you taking about?  There's no requirement to work to be able to remain in the UK.  There are three other bases that allow one to reside for over three months: study, being self sufficient, and being the family member of an EU citizen who is working, studying, or self sufficient.

Comment: @phoog You didn’t read what I wrote. “You have to work if you came to work”. Could I be clearer than that?

Comment: It's perfectly clear; it's just not correct.  An EU citizen can move to another EU country for work and then remain for one of the other reasons.